# JPA Repository null in junit tests

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to write a very basic test for my repository/service classes, but for reasons I cannot seem to figure out, my autowired repository is always null.

Here is the Repo class

```
public interface RuleRepository extends JpaRepository<Rule, UUID> {   
    public Optional<Rule> findByName(String name);
}
```

And the test

```
@DataJpaTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MyApplication.class)
public class RulesTest {
    @Autowired
    private RuleRepository ruleRepository;  

    @Test
    public void testSaveOneRule() {
        if (ruleRepository == null) {
            System.err.println("HERE");
            assertTrue(true);
        } else {
              assertTrue(false);
          }
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas? The test always passes...

Edit: I'm not sure if this is an error that deserves a new post or not, but running with the annotaion `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` yields the error `RulesTest.testSaveOneRule ? IllegalState Failed to load ApplicationContext...`

The content of MyApplication.class

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide the content of MyApplication calss? based on the error message you are getting, it can not be loaded properly.

Comment: @RezaNasiri updated!

Comment: if you are using Spring Boot, try using @SpringBootTest instead of @ ContextConfiguration to see if that helps

Comment: This results in the following error `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Configuration error: found multiple declarations of @BootstrapWith for test class [ruleTest.RulesTest]:`

Comment: what is the package name of your test case class and MyApplication?

Comment: application: `src/main/java/it.myapplication`, test class: `src/test/java/ruleTest`

Comment: can you update your package structure so if fully qualified name of your application is it.MyApplication, your test class ha s a fully qualified name of it.test.ruleTest

Answer (score 4):

For testing Repositories you should have the annotations:

```
@DataJpaTest 
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class) 
@SpringBootTest(classes=MyApplication.class)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am noticing that you are missing this annotation @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)

Comment: Trying with @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) I am faced with the error `IllegalState Failed to load ApplicationContext....` Thank you for the prompt response though!

Comment: "org.junit.jupiter.api.Test" is not compatible with @RunWith(SpringRunner.class), which is junit 4

Answer (score 1):

if you are using JPA add in class Test @DataJpaTest.
Ex.:

```java
@DataJpaTest
public class CategoriaServiceTest {
    
    @Autowired
    private CategoriaRepository repository;
    
    @Test
    public void test() {
        
        Categoria categoria = new Categoria(null, "Teste");
        
        Categoria categoriaSaved = repository.save(categoria);
        
        assertEquals(categoria.getNome(), "Jefferson");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me (to be able and load the application context also) was to use the following annotation:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
public class TestDiscountRepository {
...
```